# Python does not register column for multivariate linear regression- Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression

Link of the picture that includes all my code leading up to the problem- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu0hecajphrz8so/Annotation%202019-10-20%20124553.png?dl=0

- reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
  reg.fit(df.drop('price',axis='columns'),df.price)

  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   in 
        1 reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
  ----> 2 reg.fit(df.drop('price',axis='columns'),df.price)

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
     3938                                            index=index, columns=columns,
     3939                                            level=level, inplace=inplace,
  -> 3940                                            errors=errors)
     3941 
     3942     @rewrite_axis_style_signature('mapper', [('copy', True),

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
     3778         for axis, labels in axes.items():
     3779             if labels is not None:
  -> 3780                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
     3781 
     3782         if inplace:

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
     3810                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
     3811             else:
  -> 3812                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
     3813             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
     3814

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
     4963             if errors != 'ignore':
     4964                 raise KeyError(
  -> 4965                     '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
     4966             indexer = indexer[~mask]
     4967         return self.delete(indexer)

  KeyError: "['price'] not found in axis"

Comment: What about axis=1? Instead of columns and can you try debugging it and show the dataframe before the linear regression

Comment: Please add some description and format your question

Comment: @AmitYadav Hi. I have now included a link that shows the picture of all my codes leading up to the problem

Comment: @КристиянКацаров Hi. I have now included a link that shows all the codes leading up to the problem

Comment: Maybe Price with big P?

Comment: And axis=1, no need of column as string i think

Comment: @КристиянКацаров tried it. Did not work

Comment: @КристиянКацаров when I use ‘axis=1’, it shows me that ‘linear model is not defined

Comment: Try debugging, make a second data frame without the column and a third data frame only with the price. Feel free to share a screenshot afterwards. Usually it should work. Also the second argument should be df["Price"] and not df.price I think

Comment: @КристиянКацаров this is quite interesting and I do believe something went wrong. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j6htv3fwv214uy/Annotation%202019-10-20%20131200.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you try with `df["age"]`

Comment: @КристиянКацаров still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()

Answer (score 0):

Whats the error if you output df["age] in one cell and df["Price"] in another?